# How to show the comment line from a variable?

Tags: vba, attachmate-extra

I need to show a MsgBox with the variable value, plus the commented line from that variable.

```vb
Sub Main

Dim Sys As Object, Sess As Object, MyScreen As Object
Set Sys = CreateObject("EXTRA.System")
Set Sess = Sys.ActiveSession
Set MyScreen = Sess.Screen

Dim a(3) as string, i as integer

a(0) = "123 321 231" ' Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
a(1) = "211 321 331" ' Consectetur adipiscing elit
a(2) = "121 331 111" ' Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
a(3) = "511 321 277" ' Quis nostrud exercitation ullamco

for i = 0 to ubound(a)
  if a(i) = Sess.screen.GetString(04, 19, 11) then msgbox a(i) & "Plus the comment line"
next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you switch to using a jagged array for 'a' all will be well.

```
Sub Main()

    Dim Sys As Object, Sess As Object, MyScreen As Object
    Set Sys = CreateObject("EXTRA.System")
    Set Sess = Sys.ActiveSession
    Set MyScreen = Sess.screen

    Dim a(3) As Variant, i As Integer

    a(0) = Array("123 321 231", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet")
    a(1) = Array("211 321 331", "Consectetur adipiscing elit")
    a(2) = Array("121 331 111", "Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt")
    a(3) = Array("511 321 277", "Quis nostrud exercitation ullamco")

    For i = 0 To UBound(a)
        If a(i)(0) = Sess.screen.GetString(4, 19, 11) Then MsgBox a(i)(0) & a(i)(1)
    Next

'  Or in a more expressive way
    
'    Dim myItem As Variant
'    For Each myItem In a
'
'        If myItem(0) = Sess.screen.GetString(4, 19, 11) Then MsgBox myItem(0) & myItem(1)
'
'    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: That was an extremely fast answer! Thank you so much!

Comment: Unfortunately Attachmate Extra! V8 
which I'm using doesn't seem to have jagged arrays element, 
is there any other way to achieve similar results using this limited version of VBA? Thank you.

Comment: If the VBA you are using supports variants it will suppport jagged arrays.  An alternative approach is to use a collection or scripting.dictionary.  For a collection define a as a collection.  then you would use a.add Array("123 321 231", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet").  Getting info out is a.item(x)(y)